# How can I convert date to time ago (3 days ago) using MySQL functions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have the `Comments` table in MySQL and it looks like this

| ID | COMMENT | DATE_ADDED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | 2022-04-06 04:41:03 |
| 2 | ... | 2022-04-08 21:38:19 |
| 3 | ... | 2022-04-08 00:55:21 |
| 4 | ... | 2022-04-06 00:35:14 |
| 5 | ... | 2022-04-05 16:26:21 |
| 6 | ... | 2022-04-08 14:52:27 |
| 7 | ... | 2022-04-05 09:12:02 |
| 8 | ... | 2022-04-08 10:04:41 |
| 9 | ... | 2022-04-06 21:59:42 |
| 10 | ... | 2022-04-06 19:11:11 |

I want to convert the `DATE_ADDED` column to `a time ago` when I get the rows using `SELECT * FROM Comments`, I can do it using `PHP` language, But is it possible to do it directly by `MySQL` functions?

**In PHP language I can do it like this**

Get the current date as timestamp and get the `DATE_ADDED` column value as timestamp and after that calculate it like this, `Current Date - DATE_ADDED = Timestamp result`, After that I make conditions.

**Types of formats I want**

- Now
- Minute(s)
- Hour(s)
- Day(s)

**Examples using timestamp**

```
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (Now), If the timestamp was between 59 and less

Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (1 minute ago), If the timestamp was between 60 and 119
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (2 minutes ago), If the timestamp was between 120 and 179
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (3 minutes ago), If the timestamp was between 180 and 239
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (4 minutes ago), If the timestamp was between 240 and 299
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (5 minutes ago), If the timestamp was between 300 and 119

Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (1 hour ago), If the timestamp was between 3,600 and 7,199
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (7 hours ago), If the timestamp was between 25,200 and 28,799
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (23 hours ago), If the timestamp was between 82,800 and 86,399

Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (1 day ago), If the timestamp was between 86,400 and 172,799
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (4 days ago), If the timestamp was between 345,600 and 431,999
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (13 days ago), If the timestamp was between 1,123,200 and 1,209,599
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (184 days ago), If the timestamp was between 15,897,600 and 15,983,999
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (381 days ago), If the timestamp was between 32,918,400 and 33,004,799
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (816 days ago), If the timestamp was between 70,502,400 and 70,588,799
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (6418 days ago), If the timestamp was between 554,515,200 and 554,601,599
Show the DATE_ADDED column value like this (28118 days ago), If the timestamp was between 2,429,395,200 and 2,429,481,599
```

Comment: Fisrt compute a number of minutes with TIMESTAMPDIFF then format the result conditionally with CASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone is right when they directed you to `timestampdiff` function and `case`. There is no built-in function to do what you want. You have to write your own logic utilizing those functions. You can work a query like:

```
select a.id, a.date_added,
       (case when diff_year > 0 then concat(diff_year, ' years')
       when diff_month > 0 then concat(diff_month, ' months')
       when diff_week > 0 then concat(diff_week, ' weeks')
       when diff_day > 0 then concat(diff_day, ' days')
       when diff_hour > 0 then concat(diff_hour, ' hours')
       when diff_minute > 0 then concat(diff_minute, ' minutes')
       end) as diff_wd
from
(select id, date_added,
       timestampdiff(year, date_added, current_timestamp) as diff_year,
       timestampdiff(month, date_added, current_timestamp) as diff_month,
       timestampdiff(week, date_added, current_timestamp) as diff_week,
       timestampdiff(day, date_added, current_timestamp) as diff_day,
       timestampdiff(hour, date_added, current_timestamp) as diff_hour,
       timestampdiff(minute, date_added, current_timestamp)  as diff_minute
from comments) as a
```

The query above do run, but yes, kinda look inefficient and dumb. At least [it works](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8By65aMBMrnYgqmPyQUu1E/0). Hopefully someone come with better query.

**EDIT**

What happens with the code above is basically, on the sub-query `a` we calculate all of the `timestampdiff` function for each unit. The values are then stored in their own columns named `diff_year` for years, `diff_month` for months, `diff_week` for weeks, etc. Once we have the diffs for each unit units, the outer query selects the proper labels ("years", "months", "weeks", etc). If the column for the given label is non-zero, we will then format the output using `concat` function.

If you need to differentiate between singular and plurals, you could add more conditions checking if the "diff" value is more than one, e.g.

```
  when diff_month > 1 then concat(diff_month, ' months')
  when diff_month > 0 then concat(diff_month, ' month')
```

The conditional above will result, if the `diff_month` is 2, the output will be "2 months." However, if the `diff_month` is 1, it will be "1 month."

Comment: Okay the commands look weird but at least it is working, Could you explain the commands above to understand how it works.

Comment: I don't need weeks, months, and years formats

Comment: @luq281 - Since there is no function that does this, the above is a pretty standard way to approach it in sql.  The derived table uses [TimeStampDiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to calculate the differences in years, months, days, etc...  The outer query uses [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to display the largest one. Think of CASE as similar to a series of `if(...) elseif (....) elseif (....) else` statements.

Comment: Without weeks, months and years https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8By65aMBMrnYgqmPyQUu1E/2

Comment: @BagusTesa - Nicely done. Small things I'd suggest adding are a) handling for future dates and "Now" and b) using plurals, ie. "month(s)" vs "month" (see above link)

Comment: @luq281 - If the above answered your question, you can accept their answer by selecting the check mark next to it.

Comment: @SOS Thanks for your reply, My android app supports 5 languages `(English, Arabic, Japanese, Spanish, and French)`, I speak `Arabic` and `English` and I know how plural works in these languages but in `Japanese, Spanish, and French` languages I don't know how plural works. Is there any service it can simplify this? Thanks again.

Comment: @luq281 - Sorry I'm not aware of any services. IIRC in Spanish, the plurals are similar for words like hours (horas), minutes (minutos) and days (días) and now (ahora) is always singular.  Though I'm not sure if the use of parentheses to indicate both, like "hour(s)" is the norm for Spanish the way it is in English.

Comment: @luq281, to be honest with you, i believe things like data representation for end user better off being handled by application as close to end user itself (e.g. the "3 days ago" thing - time lapse), including localization. regarding your app, i suggest to open a new question with [tag:android] tag. afaik, android have localization support, but i havent tried it myself - so i dont know how extensive the support is.

Comment: @BagusTesa - True, it is better abstracted from the sql.  I don't know what I was thinking, haha. Glad it helped luq281 :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the type of your `DATE_ADDED` column is `timestamp`:

`select timestampdiff(<UNIT>, <later-timestamp>, <earlier-timestamp>) as diff;`

`UNIT` can be `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, `HOUR` or `SECOND` and specifies the unit you want the difference in.

Comment: This function forces me to select the unit type.

Comment: @luq281 yes, there is not gonna be a function that does it for you. Use the unit which fits your granularity, like minutes, then write your own logic to display it the way you want.

Comment: I found the answer, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TIMESTAMPDIFF() function in MySQL.

**Syntax:** TIMESTAMPDIFF(*unit*,*datetime_expr1*,*datetime_expr2*);

```
SELECT 
  ID
  ,COMMENT
  ,DATE_ADDED 
  ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, DATE_ADDED,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DIFF_TIME
FROM COMMENT;
```

More details here https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php

Comment: This function forces me to select the unit type.

Comment: You can choose different UNIT types to be used in this function (i.e. SECOND, HOUR, DAY and MONTH). More details about the valid UNIT types are here: [link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-timestampdiff/)

Comment: I should select the unit in the first parameter, But I don't know what the unit will be. It may be minutes, hours, or days. It is changing according to the timestamp

Comment: In your example, the timestamp conditions are in seconds. I would recommend to choose that unit. Then you can convert seconds to minutes, or days, or months, or etc within your case statement, depending where they fall in the range. For example if the result is 490 seconds, since it is greater than 59 seconds but less than 3600 seconds, you can convert the value into minutes to return 8 minutes ago.

Comment: I found the answer, Thanks for your time.